# Subscribing to DolphinDB stream table deployed on Docker via Python API

Tags: python, docker, streaming, subscription, dolphindb

I deployed a DolphinDB service using Docker and subscribed to a stream table from the Python client. The subscription was successful but I didn’t receive any data. Below are the node log entries:

> 2022-09-23 20:03:26.084867  :The publish connection to site localhost:20001 doesn't exist.
> 2022-09-23 20:03:26.084839  :Received a request to stop publishing table [trades] to site localhost:20001
> 2022-09-23 20:03:26.083032  :New connection from ip = 172.17.0.1 port = 58250*
> 2022-09-23 20:03:26.082969  :Created a new socket connection. Number of connections: 9* 
> 2022-09-23 20:03:26.081608  :Close a connection with index=9. Number of remaining connections: 8*
> 2022-09-23 20:03:26.081052  :AsynchronousPublisherImp::closeConnection 172.17.0.1:20001 #0 with error: Failed to connect. Connection refused*

The port on the host machine telnet `127.0.0.1 20001` was working properly.

Why was the subscribed data pushed to the port in the Docker bridge network instead? What configurations are required to receive data on the client side?

Answer (score -1):

Stream data is now pushed to the listening port on the client side. Please check whether your Docker application can access the subscription port on your host machine.